# Is there a way to configure Django JWT authorisation/confirmation emails without SMTP server?

Tags: python, django, smtp, mail-server, djoser

We are building an app with Django using Djoser and want it to send authorisation/confirmation emails to users. But the client said that there is no SMTP server on the domain he provides. So, is there some third-party api service that can send emails for our app?

While testing we used the following code (it worked):

/settings.py

```
`DJOSER = {
    "HIDE_USERS": False,
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        "user_create": "users.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer",
        "user": "users.serializers.CustomUserSerializer",
        "current_user": "users.serializers.CustomUserSerializer",
    },
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "#/activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "#/activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION": True,
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
}

...


EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = "587"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")

EMAIL_SERVER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_ADMIN = EMAIL_HOST_USER`
```